# biblatex: custom behavior for autocite and fullcite

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex with

```
\usepackage[giveninits=true, backend=bibtex, style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[online]{eprint=true}
```

Is it possible to instruct it to use options

```
doi=false, eprint=false
```

when using the command `\autocite`, but options

```
doi=true, eprint=true
```

with the command `\fullcite` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` options cannot be set differently for different `\...cite...` commands, but if you know the internal implementation behind the options, something is usually possible.

The options `doi`, `eprint`, `url`, `isbn` just set a toggle `bbx:<option>` to true or false. That can easily be done at any point, we just need a good way to hook into the relevant commands.

The following globally sets `doi` and `eptint` to false, but sets them to true in the bibliography and in `\fullcite` and `\footfullcite`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[giveninits=true, backend=bibtex, style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false, eprint=false}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[online]{eprint=true}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \toggletrue{bbx:doi}%
  \toggletrue{bbx:eprint}%
}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\toggletrue{bbx:doi}%
      \toggletrue{bbx:eprint}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\toggletrue{bbx:doi}%
      \toggletrue{bbx:eprint}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{baez/article}

Lorem \fullcite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \fullcite{baez/article}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395.]